# Button на Frame не видны? Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Всем, всем доброго дня! Объясню в чем моя проблема. Делаю интерфейс в Tkinter. Мне нужно располагать в Основном-Окне множество Кнопок (Button). Мне нужно будет менять размеры Кнопок и их местоположение, поэтому
использую упаковщик - pack().
Если помещаю Кнопки ПРЯМО в Основное-Окно, то все работает прекрасно! Но если помещаю между
Кнопками и Основным-Окном Frame-прокладку, то перестаю видеть Кнопки в Основном-Окне.
Привожу сокращение моего проекта:

```
from tkinter import *


class MainWindow:  # .....
    # (.....)
    ROWS = 7
    COLS = 10
    MINES = 10

    # (.....)
    win = Tk()
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    size = 30  # Размер Кнопки (в Пикс.) ((( ЗАДАЮЩИЙ-Атрибут !!! )))
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    win.geometry(f'{size * COLS}x{size * ROWS}')  # (+500+200)
    win.resizable(False, False)
    print(f'***  a: {win.geometry()}')  # .....

    # def __int__(self):
    #     pass

    def init_ui(self):
        # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # # (Без Frame-Прокладки)  (Кнопки - ВИДНЫ !!!)
        # rp = 0
        # for r in range(MainWindow.ROWS):
        #     cp = 0
        #     for c in range(MainWindow.COLS):
        #         # (.....)
        #         btn = Button(MainWindow.win, text=str(r) + '-' + str(c))
        #         btn.place(width=self.size, height=self.size, x=cp, y=rp)
        #         # (.....)
        #         cp += self.size
        #     # (.....)
        #     rp += self.size
        # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # (С Frame-Прокладкой)  (Кнопки - НЕ ВИДНЫ !!!)
        f_flds = Frame(MainWindow.win)  # (Frame-Прокладка)
        rp = 0
        for r in range(MainWindow.ROWS):
            cp = 0
            for c in range(MainWindow.COLS):
                # (.....)
                btn = Button(f_flds, text=str(r) + '-' + str(c))
                btn.place(width=self.size, height=self.size, x=cp, y=rp)
                # (.....)
                cp += self.size
            # (.....)
            rp += self.size
        # (.....)
        f_flds.pack()
        # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # (.....)
        self.to_screen_center()  # переместить Основное-Окно в Центр-Экрана

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @classmethod
    def to_screen_center(cls):  # переместить Основное-Окно в Центр-Экрана
        cls.win.update_idletasks()
        # (Размеры Основного-Окна)
        w_width, w_height = cls.win.winfo_width(), cls.win.winfo_height()
        # (Размеры Экрана)
        s_width, s_height = cls.win.winfo_screenwidth(), cls.win.winfo_screenheight()
        # (переместить в Центр)
        cls.win.geometry(f"+{(s_width - w_width) // 2}+{(s_height - w_height) // 2}")

    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def start(self):  # .....
        self.init_ui()
        MainWindow.win.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # (.....)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.start()
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что здесь не так?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам просто стоило добавить размеры width и height для вашего Frame. Он был очень маленький-невидимка.

```
f_flds = Frame(MainWindow.win, width=self.size * self.COLS,
                       height=self.size * self.ROWS)  # (Frame-Прокладка)
```

Вот весь код:

```
from tkinter import *


class MainWindow:  # .....
    # (.....)
    ROWS = 7
    COLS = 10
    MINES = 10

    # (.....)
    win = Tk()
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    size = 30  # Размер Кнопки (в Пикс.) ((( ЗАДАЮЩИЙ-Атрибут !!! )))
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    win.geometry(f'{size * COLS}x{size * ROWS}')  # (+500+200)
    win.resizable(False, False)
    print(f'***  a: {win.geometry()}')  # .....

    # def __int__(self):
    #     pass

    def init_ui(self):
        # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # # (Без Frame-Прокладки)  (Кнопки - ВИДНЫ !!!)
        # rp = 0
        # for r in range(MainWindow.ROWS):
        #     cp = 0
        #     for c in range(MainWindow.COLS):
        #         # (.....)
        #         btn = Button(MainWindow.win, text=str(r) + '-' + str(c))
        #         btn.place(width=self.size, height=self.size, x=cp, y=rp)
        #         # (.....)
        #         cp += self.size
        #     # (.....)
        #     rp += self.size
        # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # (С Frame-Прокладкой)  (Кнопки - НЕ ВИДНЫ !!!)
        f_flds = Frame(MainWindow.win, width=self.size * self.COLS,
                       height=self.size * self.ROWS)  # (Frame-Прокладка)
        rp = 0
        for r in range(MainWindow.ROWS):
            cp = 0
            for c in range(MainWindow.COLS):
                # (.....)

                btn = Button(f_flds, text=str(r) + '-' + str(c))
                btn.place(width=self.size, height=self.size, x=cp, y=rp)
                # (.....)
                cp += self.size
            # (.....)
            rp += self.size
        # (.....)
        f_flds.pack()
        # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # (.....)
        self.to_screen_center()  # переместить Основное-Окно в Центр-Экрана

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @classmethod
    def to_screen_center(cls):  # переместить Основное-Окно в Центр-Экрана
        cls.win.update_idletasks()
        # (Размеры Основного-Окна)
        w_width, w_height = cls.win.winfo_width(), cls.win.winfo_height()
        # (Размеры Экрана)
        s_width, s_height = cls.win.winfo_screenwidth(), cls.win.winfo_screenheight()
        # (переместить в Центр)
        cls.win.geometry(f"+{(s_width - w_width) // 2}+{(s_height - w_height) // 2}")

    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def start(self):  # .....
        self.init_ui()
        MainWindow.win.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # (.....)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.start()
```

Comment: Огромное Спасибо, Aliaksei Lz! А то я уже решил, что НИКОГДА не узнаю причины такого поведения Tkinter. Оказывается все дело в простом пустяке. В программировании пустяков не бывает!